# mysql retrieving wrong result after comparing primary key id with md5 of primary key

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

My MYSQL Result Screenshot:

[image: My MYSQL Result Screenshot]

When I run the query I have passed md5 of 105 id but in it is returning a row with id 65.

Comment: primary key datatype is bigint

Comment: Why would the md5 of your primary key equal your primary key?

Comment: May be you should compare password hash in place of primary key.

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly common mistake which pops up here from time to time.  What is happening is that the value in your `WHERE` clause:

```
65b9eea6e1cc6bb9f0cd2a47751a186f
```

is a string, but you are comparing against the `customer_id` column, which is presumably an integer.  Due to MySQL's casting rules, everything in your string beyond the first two numbers are being discarded as part of the cast.  So you really are just comparing `65` against `65`, hence the record in your result set.

For a solution, don't compare UUIDs against integer columns.  If you are searching for `65` then just use that number when searching.